# Can you change private field values of _dateData in DateTime objects using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net-core

For practice I've been trying to use reflection on several different Types. Currently I am struggling with DateTime objects. 
I'm trying to change the data in an existing DateTime object without creating a new one (Obviously not how I'm supposed to use them but this is just for excercise)

According to the source code of the DateTime class (https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/DateTime.cs) there is a private ulong field called "_dateData" that contains the actual date data of the object.
I tried changing this using reflection the normal way but this seems to not have any impact.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

FieldInfo dateData = typeof(DateTime).GetField("_dateData",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString()); // Log date before change
Console.WriteLine(dateData.GetValue(dateTime)); // Log dateData before change

dateData.SetValue(dateTime, (ulong)0); // Change dateData

Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString()); // Log date after change - No difference
Console.WriteLine(dateData.GetValue(dateTime)); // Log dateData after change - No difference
```

The code does not give any compile-time or runtime errors. I expect the snippet to actually change the value of the newly created DateTime object but it seems to not be changing anything...
My guess is that this is because _dateData is a readonly variable. If this is the case is there another way to change their values that I am missing?

Comment: "If this is the case is there another way to change their values that I am missing?" Is this just some weird academic exercise or do you have some *practical* use-case for that?

Comment: DateTime is a value type. When you call SetValue, you pass it's value in as an `object`.  That results in the DateTime being boxed (which will copy the value of the DateTime into a boxed DateTime). Then you change the value of the private field in the boxed object, you aren't changing it in the original object.  If you want to figure out how Reflection works, you'll be less confused if you restrict yourself to reference types

Comment: @HimBromBeere Just an exercise. No practical use-case besides that it might save on a very marginal amount of garbage collection time in some situations?

Comment: Again, DateTime is a value type - no garbage collection needed

Comment: @Flydog57 That makes sense. I forgot DateTime is actually struct and not a class. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible, but it cannot be achieved in the way you expect because of the fact that `DateTime` is a value type.

Instead, use the following:

```
// dateData.SetValue(dateTime, (ulong)0); // Change dateData
TypedReference typed = __makeref(dateTime);
dateData.SetValueDirect(typed, (ulong)0); // Change dateData
```

This creates a managed reference pointer to the value type in memory, allowing you to modify it via reflection.

Output:

```
12/09/2019 15:17:12
9860411019182991289
01/01/0001 00:00:00
0
```

Comment: Works, thanks a lot!
And __makeref is rather interesting to know about. Found an informative blog on it: http://benbowen.blog/post/fun_with_makeref/